# Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement. Conditional rendering component based on state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm new to React Hooks, I'm facing this error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement. when I tried to do a conditional rendering in my function component.

Here's my component:

```
export const MyComponent= () => {
  const [page, SetPage] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      {
        page === "" && <>
          <div onClick={() => SetPage("Page1")}>Show Page 1</div>
          <div onClick={() => SetPage("Page2")}>Show Page 2</div>
          <div onClick={() => SetPage("Page3")}>Show Page 3</div>
        </>
      }
      {
        page === "Page1" && Page1()
      }
      {
        page === "Page2" && Page2()
      }
      {
        page === "Page3" && Page3()
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on "Show Page 1", I expect it to display the Page1() functional component. However I get this error instead: `Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.`

I'm sure it's a stupid beginner mistake, and I tried to look through similar errors and solutions online but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I believe this is suggesting to render it as <Page1 /> instead of Page1(). I had it like <Page1 /> originally however I got the same error.

Comment: @Carrie I'm trying to replicate the error but I'm not getting anything. Are you having any other code that might be the culprit?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Actually I'm also finding out the same thing. I had put this under a different location and it works fine. I'm now suspecting it has something to do with the parent component that renders MyComponent.

Comment: I have converted my components to class components as I'm familiar with it. Everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Page1`, `Page2` and `Page3` are React components, instead of:

```
{
  page === "Page1" && Page1()
}
{
  page === "Page2" && Page2()
}
{
  page === "Page3" && Page3()
}
```

Try:

```
{
  page === "Page1" && <Page1 />
}
{
  page === "Page2" && <Page2 />
}
{
  page === "Page3" && <Page3 />
}
```

Comment: I had it like this initially, but got the same error.